# Conditional Comment/dialog to user

Tags: php, mysql

I am showing a message to all my students using MySQL for which I am using this:

```
<?php
    while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) {
        echo $row_settings['message'];
    }
?>
```

But I want to show a message to user if the *message* field is blank.

Like so.

```
if !empty(message)
show (You have not subscribed any subject)
else show (message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditon

```
<?php 
    while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) {
        if ($row_settings['message'] == '') {
            //your message
        } else {
            echo $row_settings['message']; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<?php 
while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) {
if ($row_settings['message'] == '')
{
   echo 'You have not subscribed any subject yet. Please use buy option to subscribe.';
}
else
{
    echo $row_settings['message']; 
}
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ternary operators and use the `empty` function anyway, unless the string from the database is likely to contain just '0'.

```
<?php 
while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) {
    echo !empty( $row_settings['message']) ?
       $row_settings['message'] :
       'You have not subscribed any subject yet. Please use buy option to subscribe.';
} 
?>
```

Also **stop using mysql** as mysql function calls are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php), not to mention a security risk. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO for your database interactions instead.